# How to bundle an environment dependant package?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

## problem

Currently my package is developed in a way where to import it you need to decide on your target. So:

```
import * as myLib from 'mylib/node' // if i want to use the node implementation
import * as myLib from 'mylib/web' // if i want to use the web implementation
```

The functionality is identical, the implementation differs tho because they use different APIs. I want to move to a single import that will work for node and web. To do that i changed my code to detect whether its running in node or the web. This alows me to import it like this:

```
import * as myLib from 'mylib'
```

Which works. However when i go to bundle some code using `mylib` with webpack (as web target) it goes bonkers as it tries to bundle the nodejs implementation (fails on bundling packages like `worker_threads`)

`webpack.config.ts`:

```
import * as path from 'path'
import { Configuration } from 'webpack'

const config: Configuration = {
    entry: './dist/index.js',
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        filename: 'mylib.web.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'mylib',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    mode: 'production'
}

export default config
```

## question

How can i bundle such a package or write my package in a way to support both node and web and bundle correctly.

## edits

To specify i merged web and node implementation in such manner:
Before:

```
// mylib/node
export const func = () => {
  // using worker_threads here
}

// mylib/web
export const func = () => {
  // using web worker here
}
```

After:

```
// mylib
export const func = () => {
  if(/* am i in node test */) {
    // execute the worker_threads implementation
  } else {
    // execute the web workers implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: As a workaround i've done this: `require('worker_threads'.trim())` this throws off webpack which results in skipping this dependency when bundling.